# How and where all is Ubuntu.com using metalinks?

Tags: update-manager, downloads, mirrors

I just came across [metalink](http://www.metalinker.org/). The site says ubuntu uses this. I have never seen any download link at ubuntu with a .metalink file extension (eg - ubuntu_x.yy-iso.metalink).

Also how is udpate manager getting its updates, is it by using multicast?
What is mechanism behind the updates?
How does automatic mirror selection works in ubuntu?

Comment: You'll get better answers from the community if you create a separate question for each item you want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To download Ubuntu using Metalink

Metalink files for downloading Ubuntu are available on the Ubuntu Releases server: http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/

A typical user might find this from Ubuntu's homepage by navigating to Download ▸ Alternative Downloads and then clicking "[a location near you](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download)".

Right now this is only officially used for downloading complete ISO images, but there is some [experimental work](https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/apt-metalink) being done to leverage Metalink for software updates as well.

### To use Metalink files in Ubuntu

To use Metalink files you must have a [client program that supports the Metalink standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink#Client_programs). Since Metalink is relatively new, few clients exist at this time. At a glance, the command-line program [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/aria2)) and the Firefox extension [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) look promising.

Comment: I am using Chrome, when i clicked ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.metalink it opened as a xml text file, but not as a download link. The metalink.org says chrome is supported, am i doing anything wrong. Is it to be open in someother way than just clicking on it.

Comment: I see no mention of support for Metalink in Google Chrome. Can you show me where you read this?